# codeigniter doesn't update the database

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I am trying to update my database with data from a form,
the form gets filled in with data from the daatabase.
but when i click submit it gives errors. 
can anyone help?

my controller:

```
public function update()
{
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $data['title'] = 'Update a product';

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('price', 'Price', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('publisher', 'Publisher', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('engine', 'Engine', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('release_date', 'Release date', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('platform', 'Platform', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('genre', 'Genre', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('picture', 'Picure', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('templates/header2', $data);
        $this->load->view('admin/update', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer2');

    }
    else
    {
        $this->admin_model->update_products();
        $this->load->view('admin/success');
    }
}

function input($id = 0)
{
    $this->load->helper('form');  
    $this->load->helper('html');  
    if($this->input->post('mysubmit'))
    {
        $this->admin_model->update_products();
    }
    else
    {
        $this->admin_model->set_products();
    }
    if((int)$id > 0)
    {

        $query = $this->admin_model->get($id);
        $data['id']['value'] = $query['id'];
        $data['title']['value'] = $query['title'];
        $data['price']['value'] = $query['price'];
        $data['description']['value'] = $query['description'];
        $data['publisher']['value'] = $query['publisher'];
        $data['engine']['value'] = $query['engine'];
        $data['release_date']['value'] = $query['release_date'];
        $data['platform']['value'] = $query['platform'];
        $data['genre']['value'] = $query['genre'];
        $data['picture']['value'] = $query['picture'];

}

  $this->load->view('admin/update',$data);   

}
```

my model:

```
function get($id){

    $this->load->database();

    $query = $this->db->get_where('products',array('id'=>$id));

    return $query->row_array();        

}

function update_products($data){

  $this->load->helper('url');
  $data = array(

        'id' => $this->input->post('id'),
        'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
        'price' => $this->input->post('price'),
        'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
        'publisher' => $this->input->post('publisher'),
        'engine' => $this->input->post('engine'),
        'release_date' => $this->input->post('release_date'),
        'platform' => $this->input->post('platform'),
        'genre' => $this->input->post('genre'),
        'picture' => $this->input->post('picture')            
      );

  $this->db->where('id',$id);
  $this->db->update('products',$data);  
}
```

my view:

```
<h2>Create a new product</h2>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php echo form_open('admin/update') ?>

<input type="hidden" value=<?php echo '"' . $id['value'] . '"' ?>>

<label for="title">Title</label>
<input type="text" name="title" value=<?php echo '"' . $title['value'] . '"' ?>><br><br>

<label for="price">Price</label>
<input type="number" step="any" name="price" value=<?php echo '"' . $price['value'] . '"' ?>><br><br>

<label for="description">Description</label>
<textarea name="description"><?php echo '"' . $description['value'] . '"' ?></textarea><br><br>

<label for="publisher">Publisher</label>
<input type="text" name="publisher" value=<?php echo '"' . $publisher['value'] . '"' ?>><br><br>

<label for="engine">Engine</label>
<input type="text" name="engine" value=<?php echo '"' . $engine['value'] . '"' ?>><br><br>

<label for="release_date">Release date</label>
<input type="date" name="release_date" value=<?php echo '"' . $release_date['value'] . '"' ?>><br><br>

<label for="platform">Platform</label>
<input type="text" name="platform" value=<?php echo '"' . $platform['value'] . '"' ?>><br><br>

<label for="genre">Genre</label>
<input type="text" name="genre" value=<?php echo '"' . $genre['value'] . '"' ?>><br><br>

<label for="picture">Picture</label>
<input type="text" name="picture" value=<?php echo '"' . $picture['value'] . '"' ?>><br><br>

<input type="submit" name="mysubmit" value="submit">
```

result after submit:

Create a new product

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: id

Filename: admin/update.php

Line Number: 7

""> Title
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Illegal string offset 'value'

Filename: admin/update.php

Line Number: 10

"U">

Price
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: price

Filename: admin/update.php

Line Number: 13

"">

Description

Publisher
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: publisher

Filename: admin/update.php

Line Number: 19

"">

Engine
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: engine

Filename: admin/update.php

Line Number: 22

"">

Release date
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: release_date

Filename: admin/update.php

Line Number: 25

"">

Platform
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: platform

Filename: admin/update.php

Line Number: 28

"">

Genre
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: genre

Filename: admin/update.php

Line Number: 31

"">

Picture
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: picture

Filename: admin/update.php

Line Number: 34

"">

Answer (score 0):

You have so many problems/errors in your code but I'll try to mark and fix them all. let's start...

In your `input($id = 0)` method after following line:

```
$query = $this->admin_model->get($id);
```

You have code like this:

```
$data['id']['value'] = $query['id'];
```

Change all of them to:

```
$data['id'] = $query['id'];
$data['title'] = $query['title'];
// more...
```

Remove `['value']` from all of them. Then in your `view` you have variables (array) like:

```
$id['value']
$title['value']
```

Remove `['value']` from those and just use `$title` and so on for every variable/field. Then in your view again make changes from this:

```
<?php echo form_open('admin/update') ?>
```

To this:

```
<?php echo form_open('admin/update/' . $id) ?>
```

Also remove `<input type="hidden" value=<?php echo '"' . $id['value'] . '"' ?>>` and finally in `update_products` method, change it to:

```
function  update_products($id)
{
    //...
}
```

From `$data` array in `update_products` method; remove this:

```
'id' => $this->input->post('id'),
```

Hope this will work but you had many errors so not sure if I could have marked them all.Give it a try.

**Update:** You are calling `update_products` from `update` so you should pass the `id` to `update` method so make changes in, add the `$id` parameter:

```
public function update($Id)
{
    //...
}
```

Then in this method where you are calling the `update_products` method pass the `$id` with it like this:

```
$this->admin_model->update_products($id);
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but i get the same errors.
it also says that the $id in: <?php echo form_open('admin/update/' . $id) ?> is an undefined variable.
and in the input fields after submit is code like: <div

Comment: Don't you have `$data['id'] = $query['id'];` in your `input` method ?

Comment: i just looked at the shop where the products are looped and every time i tried to update, it created another product without any entries, so something is wrong there. i'm going to look at it

Comment: You are not passing the `id` for `where` clause in the update method.

Comment: i have that in my input method yeah.
i have seen that if i click submit he chooses:
`$this->admin_model->set_products();`

Comment: do you mean this?
`$this->db->where('id',$id);`

Comment: i am passing the id for the where clause i think yeah